# PLS-00382: expression is of wrong type in Oracle cursor

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, cursor, dynamicquery

I have written a cursor in oracle 11g as follows:

```
DECLARE CURSOR QnA_cursor IS 
        SELECT activity_id, question, answer 
        FROM TABLE1
        WHERE question != 'surveyText'
        ORDER BY activity_id, question;

        cur_count       INT := 1;
        que             NVARCHAR2(10);
        ans             NVARCHAR2(10);
        sqlCommand      NVARCHAR2(500);
        RowCountVar     INT;
    BEGIN
        FOR QueAns
        IN QnA_cursor
        LOOP
            IF cur_count = 4 THEN cur_count := 1; END IF;   /* We have only 3 questions for each activity_id */
            que := 'question' || cur_count;     /* question1, question2, question3 */
            ans := 'answer' || cur_count;       /* answer1, answer2, answer3 */

            sqlCommand := 'UPDATE TABLE2 SET '||que||' = :1, '||ans||' = :2 WHERE activity_id = :3';
            EXECUTE IMMEDIATE sqlCommand USING QueAns.question, QueAns.answer, QueAns.activity_id;

            cur_count := cur_count + 1;
        END LOOP;
    END;
```

This is the schema for TABLE1 and TABLE2:

```
Create table TABLE2(
ACTIVITY_ID             NUMERIC(19,0),
QUESTION1               NVARCHAR2(2000),
ANSWER1                 NVARCHAR2(2000),
QUESTION2               NVARCHAR2(2000),
ANSWER2                 NVARCHAR2(2000),
QUESTION3               NVARCHAR2(2000),
ANSWER3                 NVARCHAR2(2000)
)

Create table TABLE1(
ACTIVITY_ID             NUMERIC(19,0),
QUESTION                NVARCHAR2(2000),
ANSWER                  NVARCHAR2(2000)
)
```

When I try to compile it in sqldeveloper, I am getting following error at the line where I execute the dynamic query 'EXECUTE IMMMEDIATE':

```
PLS-00382: expression is of wrong type
```

I have played around it a lot, but couldn't figure out the reason. The data types are same for corresponding columns in both the table. Can you please tell me what can be a problem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change the datatype of sqlCommand from NVARCHAR2 to varchar2. Execute immediate expects varchar, varchar2 or char. Code given below should work

```
DECLARE
  CURSOR qna_cursor IS
    SELECT activity_id,
           question,
           answer
      FROM table1
     WHERE question != 'surveyText'
     ORDER BY activity_id,
              question;
  cur_count   INT := 1;
  que         VARCHAR2(10);
  ans         VARCHAR2(10);
  sqlcommand  VARCHAR2(500); --> Should be varchar, varchar2 or char
  rowcountvar INT;
BEGIN
  FOR queans IN qna_cursor LOOP
    IF cur_count = 4 THEN
      cur_count := 1;
    END IF; /* We have only 3 questions for each activity_id */
    que := 'question' || cur_count; /* question1, question2, question3 */
    ans := 'answer' || cur_count; /* answer1, answer2, answer3 */
    sqlcommand := 'UPDATE TABLE2 SET ' || que || ' = :1, ' || ans || ' = :2 WHERE activity_id = :3';
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE sqlcommand USING queans.question, queans.answer, queans.activity_id;
    cur_count := cur_count + 1;
  END LOOP;
END;
/
```